# How Can I bound this integral?

Tags: integration, limits

How to show that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\int_1^{x-1}{t\sin\left(\frac{4}{t^2}\right)dt}}=\infty$$

I rewrite it as:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\int_1^{x-1}{\frac{\left(\frac{4}{t^2}\right)t\sin\left(\frac{4}{t^2}\right)}{\left(\frac{4}{t^2}\right)}dt}}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}{\int_1^{x-1}{\frac{4}{t}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\frac{4}{t^2}\right)}{\frac{4}{t^2}}   dt}}$$

And  now can I just bound $\frac{\sin\left(\frac{4}{t^2}\right)}{\frac{4}{t^2}} $ by $\frac{1}{4}$?

so I get:
$${\int_1^{x-1}{\frac{4}{t}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\frac{4}{t^2}\right)}{\frac{4}{t^2}}   dt}}\geq^{(*)} \int_1^{x-1}{\frac{1}{t}}=\ln|x-1|\longrightarrow_{x\to\infty}\infty  $$
I know (*) is true for $t>10$ but is it enough? 
Why/why not?

(I can't really find the theorem/lemma for that)

Comment: It is enough, just split the integral into one part from 1 to 10 and one from 10 to $x-1$. The first part will be finite (why?) and the second one will be equal to $\ln(x-1)- \ln(10)$ which tends to plus infinity.

Comment: $\sin(\frac4{t^2})/\frac4{t^2}$ is bounded by $1$, not $\frac14$. But fixing that doesn't cause any problems.